# what is "sys/videoio.h"?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, opencv

trying to install opencv on my centos6
and always got this error meesage

```
fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
#include <sys/videoio.h>
```

Anybody understand what sys/videoio.h is? where do I get a file like this one?

Comment: I see quite a few people having problem with this,but not a single answer posted.I must happen to most people installing OpenCV,wonder how they fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is a workaround by deselecting WITH_V4L and selecting WITH_LIBV4L in cmake-gui which  stop checking for sys/videoio.h.Again,same as other solutions I posted, I do not known why it is working this way.

[image]